# Doxygen warning when using a macro inside an anonymous struct

Tags: c, doxygen, anonymous-struct

I have a struct, and by convention, I need to use a certain macro in order to declare a variable of that type:

the struct:

```
struct basic_struct {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

the macro:

```
#define BASIC_VAR(var_name) struct basic_struct var_name
```

I encountered a problem with Doxygen when using this macro inside an anonymous struct, as follows:

```
struct {
    BASIC_VAR(var_1);
    int var_2;
} my_struct;
```

I get the Doxygen warning:

```
warning: no uniquely matching class member found for BASIC_VAR(var_1)
```

when:

1) dropping the macro

```
struct {
    struct basic_struct var_1;
    int var_2;
} my_struct;
```

2) not using anonymous struct

```
 struct my_struct_t {
    BASIC_VAR(var_1);
    int var_2;
} my_struct;
```

I get no warnings.
But I have to use the macro, and I prefer to keep using the anonymous struct, there's any Doxygen command I can use to avoid this warning?

Comment: why do you have to use the macro? it doesn't make for very readable code

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to set `MACRO_EXPANSION` to `YES` in the Doxyfile so that Doxygen will expand your macro. See http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html

Additionally, you may need to add your macro to the PREDEFINED tag.

Comment: OK so this was set to YES already, but I did look at that link, and adding "BASIC_VAR(var1)=" to PREDEFINED tag solved the problem! For some reason, setting EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF tag to NO didn't. Anyway, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I used was to edit the Doxyfile:

1) make sure that MACRO_EXPANSION tag is set to YES

2) in PREDEFINED tag add the macro followed with = operator, without spaces, in my case: BASIC_VAR(var_1)=

For some reason, setting MACRO_EXPANSION tag to YES and EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF to NO didn't work.